# Issue trying to get a example Parsley app working

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, parsley

I'm getting started on a new project at I'm trying to get an Parsley example to work.
Here is the demo url: http://files.152.org/flex_examples/parsley/
View source is enabled

I have parsley registered in the app and can get the albums in the left column loaded. The part I'm stuck at is trying to get a message to PictureTile.as so images will load in the TileList.

Can anyone that has Parsley experience lend a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Metric152.
I'm trying to get to grips with Parsley/Pimento too.
You might want to take a look at the series of blog posts
http://artinflex.blogspot.com/

Also
http://coenraets.org/blog/2009/07/building-a-flex-application-with-the-parsley-framework/

Comment: I'll look through your blog post. I've seen the second link you suggested before. It helped me with some stuff, but couldn't solve my issue. The forum for parsley has been useless. I'm thinking of checking out robot legs for my next example project.